# Hibernate id returns clasCastException

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence, classcastexception

I've been given this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
[...]
```

It says me so, because hibernate it's trying to map the `ID`, and hopes to receive an `String` field, but in spite of that, it's receiving an `Integer`. This is part of my entity:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "platform_seq", sequenceName = "SQ_PLATFORM_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "platform_seq")
@Id
@Column(name = "PLATFORM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
[...]
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

As you can hope, the database field "`PLATFORM_ID`" is a `number`:

```
PLATFORM_ID NUMBER(38,0)
```

and the sequence is a normal sequence (getting a number, increasing by 1...)

```
SEQUENCE_NAME   SQ_PLATFORM_ID
MIN_VALUE   1
MAX_VALUE   9999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
LAST_NUMBER 21
```

The line that is throwing this error is this:

```
getSession().createCriteria(c).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id).ignoreCase()).uniqueResult();
```

where `c` is a `Class` and `id` is an `String` (not null obviously)

I've also tried to pass id as an Integer, but with the same results:

```
getSession().createCriteria(c).add(Restrictions.eq("id", new Integer(id)).ignoreCase()).uniqueResult();
```

The thing is that, if i change the Entity datatype to `String`, it works fine! but i want to know why is working like this exactly.

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to remove `.ignoreCase()`?

`ignoreCase()` only makes sense for `String`s, and perhaps that's why Hibernate treats value as a `String`.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much!!